# scichart3d geometry object select Is it impossible?

Tags: wpf, scichart

I want to implement in scichart3d viewport3d geometry object select
entity object (viewport3d geometry object) selection is not Support.
so i think I tried to put a series in the inside of an object so that I could select it.
but series overwritten with viewport3d object are not selected.
so I made it disappear temporarily when I clicked on an object, but it was not practical enough.

Below is an example I wrote.
I hope I can help you see this.

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ENkmUqdbJL3j4zDKuacA9pCviuQLRvK5)

Is there any other way to implement the ability to select viewport3d geometry objects?